# Array nil (even when addObject:)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [addObject: to array not working (array still nil)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560898/addobject-to-array-not-working-array-still-nil)

EVERYTHING UPDATED

This app is a table view with a tab bar controller. I am logging the count of the array:     arrayOfFavourites and even though i add an object is continues to have a nil value, my relating code, all objects shown are allocated and initialized in the code (previous or present) some are instances and some are properties:

### ListViewController.m:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"TOUCHED CELL!");

    // Push the web view controller onto the navigation stack - this implicitly 
    // creates the web view controller's view the first time through
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

    // Grab the selected item
    entry = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if (!entry) {
        NSLog(@"!entry");
    }

    // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Load the request into the web view 
    [[webViewController webView] loadRequest:req];

    // Take the cell we pressed
    // IMPORTANT PART
    CELL = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [webViewController setItem:entry];

    webViewController = nil;
    webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
    [entry release];
}
```

### WebViewController.m:

You shake to favorite a cell

```
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    cellToPassOn = nil;

    NSLog(@"Favouriting"); // YES I KNOW SPELLING

    // This is pretty simple, what we do is we take the cell we touched and take its title  and link 
    // then put it inside an array in the Favourites class

    Favourites *fav = [[Favourites alloc] init];
    ListViewController *list = [[ListViewController alloc] init];
    [self setCellToPassOn: [list CELL]];

    if (!item) {
        NSLog(@"NILLED ITEM");
    }

    [[fav arrayOfFavourites] addObject:[item autorelease]];
    [fav setCell: cellToPassOn];
}
```

### Favourites.m:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"ROWS NO.");
    NSLog(@"%i", [arrayOfFavourites count]);

    return [arrayOfFavourites count];
}
```

### Favourites:

A CLASS, ON TAB BAR CONTROLLER

WEBVIEWCONROLLER:

CONTROLLER FOR DIFFERENT WEB VIEWS

LISTVIEWCONTROLLER:

DATA PROVIDER

Actually what happens is when i shake i reload the table view data and i add an object to an array (array of favorites) the count is one.... GOOD! But then when i shake again (in a different article, my app has different webViews when i press different cells.) It is still 1... weird.... if i go to favorites class that array remains one.. ok... so as you can see i am returning the arrayOfFavourites count to numberOfRowsInSection (which is 1) but no cells appear and the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called (using an NSLOG) why is this happening I AM VERY ANNOYED!

Answer (score 3):

In your Favourites.m `numberOfRowsInSection` function, looks like you should do this:

```
if(arrayOfFavourites == NULL)
{
    arrayOfFavourites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Because you're reinitializing (and likely leaking) in every single call to `numberOfRowsInSection` (which gets called each time the table needs to know how many rows it must display -- i.e. very often).

Answer (score 2):

You create and destroy a new Favourites object every time you go through `-motionBegan:withEvent:`, and you create a new array every time you go through `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. If you want data to persist beyond those events, you need to keep the objects around.

Comment: Yeah, and this too (and +1 to you).

Comment: ok :

This is what happens now after i got rid of the release:

Comment: ok i got rid of the release and nil
Now what happens:

If i shake in a webView, count turns to one.... excellent
If i shake in a different webView, count still one not two... weird
When i go to the favorites view the count remains one and not nil... good.... (count recorded inside numberOfRowsInSection), i return the  arrays count which is one but no cells appear because the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called (i put an NSLOG there)

Comment: BTW The allocation and initialization of the arrayOfFavourites in numberOfRowsInSection was an accident while pasting the code in stack overflow... i got rid of it, i don't need it as I'm allocating the array (arr) in web view controller to arrayOfFavourites  in Favourites so it shouldn't be nil

Answer (score 1):

Let review this part of your code :

```
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

cellToPassOn = nil;
NSLog(@"Favouriting"); // YES I KNOW SPELLING

// This is pretty simple, what we do is we take the cell we touched and take its title  and link 
// then put it inside an array in the Favourites class

// HERE you are creating a NEW fav
Favourites *fav = [[Favourites alloc] init];
// HERE you are creating a NEW list
ListViewController *list = [[ListViewController alloc] init];
//  SO HERE what is "CELL" doing, returning some constant or static object?
[self setCellToPassOn: [list CELL]];

// HERE what is item and where does it come from
if (!item) {
    NSLog(@"NILLED ITEM");
}

// Here you take an array of an object you just created and autoreleasing the item
// this is not the regular way to handle memory management in Cocoa, 
// depending on what you are doing to item else where you could get item == deallocated pretty soon
[[fav arrayOfFavourites] addObject:[item autorelease]];
[fav setCell: cellToPassOn];

HERE you are releasing fav
[fav release];
HERE fav don't exist anymore as well as the array to which you've added something to it.
[list release];
item = nil;
}
```

Unless I'm reading your code incorrectly I have the feeling that you are trying to have some persistence with "volatile" object.

You need to make a `@property` for those object to survive longer that one method call.
Every time you create a new object it's new and have no knowledge of the precedent one.

And if we look at this code :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// HERE everytime the tableview is asking for the numberOfRowsInSection, you create a new array 
// And that new empty array is replacing your old one.  
// That is your "weird" thing, it's doing what you are asking it to do, set it back to a new empty array.
arrayOfFavourites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"ROWS NO.");
NSLog(@"%i", [arrayOfFavourites count]);

return [arrayOfFavourites count];
}
```

Comment: ok i edited the question to show my new code (still doesn't work though)..... item is an object of the class RSSItem which takes an XML and parses it and finds its item. That object is made in ListViewController and is transported to WebViewController which is added to the array. Cell (from listviewcontroller) is a UITableViewCell which i need for its contentView in Favourites.

Anyways what is happening here is i have a tableView in ListViewController, when i press a cell from it, it goes to an article i parsed from XML from apple rss feed....

Comment: i want to favorite that article so you shake while you're in the article and add it as a cell to favorites how do i do this.....

Anyways check my edited question

Comment: @user973985 Cell (from listviewcontroller) is a UITableViewCell which i need for its contentView in Favourites. CELL is that a constant, or something that you are creating at initialization state, because you are calling it on a newly allocated object. and from your past code you had problems with that paradigm. You are not getting back this :  CELL = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; because it was set on an other object.  And you should cache what you need to remake a cell, not the cell itself.

Comment: oh ok i  have done that..... any ideas on the array which nils on arrival in favorites and will not go further than the count of one??

Comment: webViewController = nil;

and



    webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

Comment: and now the arrayOfFavourites no longer becomes nil

Comment: which is good but the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called
even weirder

Comment: correction:

Actually the array does become nil upon arrival at Favourites

Comment: @user973985 Have you read carefully the comment that I've posted inside your code in my answer? Because your updated code is still showing the problems that I've pointed out. And those problem are more about understanding how object oriented programming work, especially how class and object (instance) work. You are using class as instance, and that doesn't work that way.

Comment: @user973985 now `-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is just leaking 2 objects but the rest is still true, in that method you are still creating new object to store item that you want to see later, but when the method end, you don't have a pointer to them anymore. without the `release` those object are still alive, but not reachable.

Comment: so how can i fix this???

Comment: @user973985 : instance variables or property is what you need if you want stuff to live more than a method call.  You need to check for scoop of variable and to revise how object oriented programming work. There is tutorial and good books on the subject.